# Trigger file copy upon device insertion (without depending on systemd)

Tags: linux, bash, usb-storage, udev, automount

I would like to automatically have some files form a storage device copied upon its insertion. I am looking to use one and the same method on both systems which use systemd and systems using init scripts (e.g. OpenRC on Gentoo). Additionally, I would seek to not break automounting.

I gather from many other questions dealing with this issue that this is best done via udev, and it almost works, if not for the udev posthook bein executed strictly before the automount (in a way in which udev checks for the exit status of any scripts it called and any scripts that script calls, by some process which to me looks like magic):

The script execution works, just that the file cannot be copied, because (I believe) the automount trigger waits for the copy script to finish first:

```
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-local.rules 
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="4C3D-8BCB", RUN+="/bin/su chymera -c /home/chymera/.repositorg/transfer/4C3D-8BCB.sh"
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ cat 4C3D-8BCB.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch ~/lalax.txt
cp "/run/media/chymera/NIKON D750/lala.txt" ~/
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ ls ~/lal*
/home/chymera/lalax.txt
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ ls /run/media/chymera/NIKON\ D750/
DCIM  lala.txt  NIKON001.DSC
```

Adding sleep, and diverting the script execution to a subshell, does not seem to work.
The file does not become accessible, because now automount is inhibited completely:

```
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-local.rules 
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="4C3D-8BCB", RUN+="/bin/su chymera -c /home/chymera/.repositorg/transfer/_4C3D-8BCB.sh"
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ cat _4C3D-8BCB.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nohup /bin/bash /home/chymera/.repositorg/transfer/4C3D-8BCB.sh & exit
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ cat 4C3D-8BCB.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch ~/lalax.txt
sleep 5
cp "/run/media/chymera/NIKON D750/lala.txt" ~/
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ ls ~/lal*
/home/chymera/lalax.txt
chymera@quiethost ~/.repositorg/transfer $ ls /run/media/chymera/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to (sanely) implement with just udev, because udev only rebroadcasts the "device added" event after all rules and all workers have finished on that device. (And the event is what triggers automount, generally.)

Instead of reacting to devices, you want to react to *new mounts*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wanted_dir="/run/media/chymera/NIKON D750"

findmnt -o action,target -r -n --poll |
    while read -r eaction etarget; do
        if [[ "$eaction" == mount && "$etarget" == "$wanted_dir" ]]; then
            cp this that etc.
        fi
    done
```

Comment: So I add this as a service and keep it running in perpetuity?
I'm still wondering, though, how udev can keep track of orphaned processes started b its workers (even in subshells).